# Pool Game is Not Working

Tags: processing

hi I have this code and I just want the pools to disappear when they reach one of the 4 holes, and if the white ball goes to any of the holes the game should reset or end

that is the code:
 the game is already working fine except what was mention above. I would really appreciate any kind of help.

```java
    /**
     * Welcome to the pool game *  
     * Click, drag and release on a ball to give it a push
     * numerical keys 1-4 respawns different number of balls **/
    Table game;
    //--------------
    void setup()
    {
        size(210, 330);
        smooth();
        game = new Table(6, 5, 200, 300);
        game.startGame();
    }
    //--------------
    void draw() {
        background(32);
        game.update();
        game.visualize();
        fill(0);
        ellipse(6, 7, 20, 20);
        ellipse(195, 7, 20, 20);
        ellipse(6, 295, 20, 20);
        ellipse(195, 295, 20, 20);

    }
    //--------------
    void keyPressed() {
        println( game.kineticEnergy() );
    }
    //--------------
    void mousePressed() {
        game.mousePressed(mouseX-game.x, mouseY-game.y);
    }
    //--------------
    void mouseReleased() {
        game.mouseReleased(mouseX-game.x, mouseY-game.y);
    }
    //=============================
    class Table {
        float drag = 0.985;
        float elasticity = 0.9;
        float wallElasticity = 0.8;
        float pushFactor = 0.05;
        float maxPush = 10; color[] ballColors =new color[]  {color(192),color(192,64,32), color(64, 192, 0)};
        Ball[] balls;
        Ball selectedBall;
        int x, y, width, height;
        //--------------
        Table(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            width = w;
            height = h;
        }
        //--------------
        void startGame() {
            buildBalls(8);
        }//--------------
        void buildBalls(int count)
        {
            balls = new Ball[2*count+1];
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
                balls[i] = new Ball( random(width), random(height), 1, this);
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
                balls[count+i] = new Ball( random(width), random(height), 2, this);
            balls[2*count] = new Ball( 0.5*(width), 0.5*(height), 0, this);
        }
        //--------------
        void update() {
            //simulation
            for (int i=0; i<balls.length; i++)
                balls[i].update();
            //collision detection
            for (int i=0; i<balls.length; i++)
                for (int j=i+1; j<balls.length; j++)
                    balls[i].collisionDetect(balls[j]);
        }
        //--------------
        void visualize() {
            translate(x, y);
            noStroke();
            fill(0, 128, 0);
            rect(0, 0, width, height);
            //draw que
            stroke(255);
            if (mousePressed && selectedBall != null)
                line(selectedBall.x, selectedBall.y, mouseX-x, mouseY-y);
            //drawing
            for (int i=0; i<balls.length; i++)
                balls[i].visualize();
        }
        //--------------
        float kineticEnergy() {
            float energy=0;
            for (int i=0; i<balls.length; i++)
                energy += mag( balls[i].vx, balls[i].vy );
            return energy;
        }
        //--------------
        void mousePressed(int mx, int my)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<balls.length; i++)
                if ( dist(balls[i].x, balls[i].y, mx, my) < balls[i].radius){                      
                    selectedBall = balls[i];
                    break;
                }
        }
        //--------------
        void mouseReleased(int mx, int my) {
            if (selectedBall != null) {
                float px = (selectedBall.x-mx) * pushFactor;
                float py = (selectedBall.y-my) * pushFactor;
                float push = mag(px, py);
                if ( push > maxPush ) {
                    px = maxPush*px/push;
                    py = maxPush*py/push;
                }
                selectedBall.push(px, py);
            }
            selectedBall = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a new line before your class `class Ball` so the indentation can be visible

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please try to narrow your problem down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're only really asking about one specific thing, disappearing a ball when it collides with a corner, so we really don't need to see any of the other logic.

But basically, you would need to use the `dist()` function and check the ball's distance from each corner. Here's a small example that does that with a single ball and single corner:

```
//keep track of whether the ball is disappeared
boolean alive = true;

//keep track of the hole's location and size
float holeX;
float holeY;
float holeSize;

//keep track of the ball size
float ballSize = 20;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);

  holeX = width*.75;
  holeY = height*.75;
  holeSize = width/4;
}

void draw() {

  background(0);

  //is the ball still on the table?
  if (alive) {

    //draw the ball
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, ballSize, ballSize);

    //check the ball against the hole
    if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, holeX, holeY) < ballSize/2 + holeSize/2) {
      //if they collide, disappear the ball
      alive = false;
    }
  }

  //draw the hole
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(holeX, holeY, holeSize, holeSize);
}
```

You would have to do the same thing for each ball and each corner. If you're still stuck, please try to work from a small example like this one instead of your entire sketch. Good luck.